# ExecutorService which runs tasks in calling thread?

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

Are there any `java.util.ExecutorService` implementations which simply run all executed tasks in the calling thread? If this isn't included in Java by default, is there a library which contains an implementation like this?

Comment: See the [documentation on `Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html); see their `DirectExecutor`? With a little work, you can turn it into an `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only existing implementation I could find is [`SynchronousExecutorService`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.10.0/org/apache/camel/util/concurrent/SynchronousExecutorService.java/) - unfortunately buried somewhere in [camel](/questions/tagged/camel) library.

Pasting source code (without comments) here for future reference:

```
package org.apache.camel.util.concurrent;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SynchronousExecutorService extends AbstractExecutorService {

    private volatile boolean shutdown;

    public void shutdown() {
        shutdown = true;
    }

    public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isShutdown() {
        return shutdown;
    }

    public boolean isTerminated() {
        return shutdown;
    }

    public boolean awaitTermination(long time, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {
        return true;
    }

    public void execute(Runnable runnable) {
        runnable.run();
    }

}
```

Comment: Should probably verify that it's not shutdown in `execute`.

Comment: @veer: true, but it's not my code. Feel free to contact Camel developers.

Comment: True, true, but I meant it to be more of a suggestion towards the OP, not you... :p

Answer (score 6):

You may use Guava com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor() which does exactly what you want: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/0434c5199c83c3f43b8b6a86c62e121d518fe7d0/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.java#L267

EDIT: The method has been renamed to com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.newDirectExecutorService()
https://github.com/google/guava/blob/f67ab864bde63fa6602b5688de0440957ffeaa2e/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.java#L369

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: Yes. I tried running it with 0 threads and a thread rejection policy of "Caller Runs," but that fails with an exception.