# How to run ScalaZ Task in current thread

Tags: scala, concurrency, task, scalaz

It should be simple, but I have no idea how to do it. I want to run ScalaZ Task in the current thread. I was surprised `task.run` doesn't run on the current thread, as it is synchronous.

Is it possible to run it on the current thread, and how to do it?

Comment: Have a look at unsafeStart description from here.  http://timperrett.com/2014/07/20/scalaz-task-the-missing-documentation/

Answer (score 0):

There were some updates and deprecations since http://timperrett.com/2014/07/20/scalaz-task-the-missing-documentation/.

Right now the recommended way of calling task synchronously is:

```
task.unsafePerformSync        // returns result or throws exception
task.unsafePerformSyncAttempt // returns -\/(error) or \/-(result)
```

Keep in mind, though, that it is not exactly done in the caller's thread - the execution is perfomed in a thread pool defined for a task, but the caller's thread blocks until the execution is finished. There is no way of making the task run *exactly* in the same thread.

Comment: It's not entirely correct "the execution is perfomed in a thread pool defined for a task". Consider this `Task.delay("aaa").map(_ + 1)`. Did it ask for any thread-pool during compilation?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if `Task.async` is used - there is no way to make composite `Task` always stay in the same thread as `cb` (callback) can be called from any place (any thread), so that in a chain like:

```
 Task
   .delay("aaa")
   .map(_ + "bbb")
   .flatMap(x => Task.async(cb => completeCallBackSomewhereElse(cb, x)))
   .map(_ + "ccc")
   .unsafePerformSync
```

`_ + "bbb"` is gonna be executed in a caller's thread

`_ + "ccc"` is gonna be executed in `Somewhereelse`'s thread as scalaz have no control over it.

Basically, this allows a `Task` to be a powerful instrument for asynchronous operations, so it might not even know about underlying thread pools or even implement behavior without pure threads and wait/notify.

However, there are special cases where it might work as caller-runs:

1) No `Strategy`/`Task.async` related stuff:

```
Task.delay("aaa").map(_ + "bbb").unsafePerformSync
```

`unsafePerformSync` uses [CountDownLatch](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/release/7.0.6/concurrent/src/main/scala/scalaz/concurrent/Future.scala#L156) to await for result of `runAsync`, so if there is no async/non-deterministic operations on the way - `runAsync` will use [caller's thread](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/release/7.0.6/concurrent/src/main/scala/scalaz/concurrent/Future.scala#L137):

```
  /** 
   * Run this `Future`, passing the result to the given callback once available. 
   * Any pure, non-asynchronous computation at the head of this `Future` will
   * be forced in the calling thread. At the first `Async` encountered, control
   * switches to whatever thread backs the `Async` and this function returns.
   */
  def runAsync(cb: A => Unit): Unit = 
    listen(a => Trampoline.done(cb(a)))
```

2) You have control over execution strategies. So [this simple Java trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941617/executorservice-which-runs-tasks-in-calling-thread) will help. Besides, it's already implemented in scalaz and called `Strategy.sequential`

---

P.S.

1) If you simply want to start a computation as soon as possible use `task.now`/`Task.unsafeStart`.

2) If you want something less heavily related on asynchronous stuff but still lazy and stack-safe, you might take a look here (it's for Cats library) http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Eval.html

3) If you just need to encapsulate side-effects - take a look at [`scalaz.effect`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/series/7.3.x/effect/src/main/scala/scalaz/effect)